# make 2nd column within array after some rows in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have more then 50 rows in my JSON array. I want to display 25 in one column and others in Second Colum. At the moment all displaying in one column. please check my code and help with thanks

```
 <Row>
   <Col md="6">
    <Table>  
    
   formsList.map((item, index) => {
       
    return(
     <tr>
      <td>
          <div className="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <input
              className="custom-control-input"
              id= {item.id}
              name= {item.checkBoxfieldName}
              type="checkbox"
              value={item.id}
            />
            <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={item.id}>
               {item.form_title}
            </label>
          </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      )
    })}
   
    </Table>
    </Col>
 </Row>
```

I want to display my extra rows in 2nd < Col md="6" > after 25 rows. please help with thanks

Comment: this is working code in react? :o

Comment: @gabor.zed yes this is working for one column only . I want to add second column after specific rows.

Comment: you can go trough the array with two for loops. one for the first 25 and one for the rest. Could you share the whole file maybe the project?

Comment: @gabor.zed yes I was also thinking about this that I should make two loops for two columns. I posted question that may be get this solution in one loop. As this was easy in PHP.
Thanks gabor